# Converting QLineEdit text to float - PySide/pyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt4, pyside

How do I convert a number in a LineEdit widget to float?

Say I have:

```
textfield = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
```

And the user inputs 12345.2 in it. I want that to be converted to a float and stored in a variable X. How do I do it?

I tried the code below, it doesn't work.

```
INPUT = textfield.text
INPUT2 = float(INPUT)
```

Comment: You should also make the qlineedit only accept numbers. I believe it's done with something like textfield.setInputMask("0.00"). Will check when not on my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`text`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlineedit.html#text-prop) is the name of the method. You should call it to get the text inside the `QLineEdit`.

```
INPUT = textfield.text()
INPUT2 = float(INPUT)
```

Comment: @HelloUni I strongly recommend adding a `QDoubleValidator` constraint to the `QLineEdit` which prevents it to send something else than a floating-point number further down the chain.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
INPUT2 = float(INPUT)

You have INPUT2 where you should have INPUT

Comment: Better yet
INPUT2 = float(textfield.text)

Comment: oops sorry that was a typo I actually tried INPUT2 = float(INPUT). It doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure the text is a number?

Comment: print "Hello World!\n";
print (float("12354") + 10)
output:
Hello World!

12364.0

Comment: I know that. The thing is that the QLineEdit uses QString not basic python String ('str'). I was asking whether there might any way to convert it to float.